# How to get the complete object / array with jq?

Tags: json, jq, weaviate

I'm running:

```
$ jq ".environments[] | select(.name | contains(\"docker\")) | .database.database_config.host = \"${DGRAPHIP}\"" weaviate.conf.json
```

on this file: https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/blob/develop/weaviate.conf.json

The output of this is (if `DGRAPHIP = 1.2.3.4`):

```
{
  "name": "docker",
  "database": {
    "name": "dgraph",
    "database_config": {
      "host": "1.2.3.4", <== THIS IS GOOD!
      "port": 9080
    }
  },
  "schemas": {
    "Thing": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weaviate/weaviate-semantic-schemas/master/weaviate-Thing-ontology-s
chema_org.min.json",
    "Action": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weaviate/weaviate-semantic-schemas/master/weaviate-Action-ontology
-schema_org.min.json"
  },
  "mqttEnabled": false
}
```

This is not the desired outcome, I would like the outcome to be encapsulated like:

```
{
    "environments": [{
        RESULTS
    }]
}
```

Comment: Do you want just the `docker` environment in the result, or all the other environments (unmodified) as well?

Comment: Tip: don't use interpolation to create the filter; pass `$DGRAPHID` as a real argument. This simplifies the quoting as well: `jq --arg newhost "$DGRAPHID" '.environment ... | .database.database_config.host = $newhost'`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Makes complete sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple adjustment:

```
jq --arg dgraphip "1.2.3.4" '{"environments" : .environments 
 | map(select(.name | contains("docker")) 
 | .database.database_config.host = $dgraphip)}' weaviate.conf.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "docker",
      "database": {
        "name": "dgraph",
        "database_config": {
          "host": "1.2.3.4",
          "port": 9080
        }
      },
      "schemas": {
        "Thing": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weaviate/weaviate-semantic-schemas/master/weaviate-Thing-ontology-schema_org.min.json",
        "Action": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weaviate/weaviate-semantic-schemas/master/weaviate-Action-ontology-schema_org.min.json"
      },
      "mqttEnabled": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: damn, I could _not_ figure it out on my own. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which uses [update assignment `|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:|=) with [map](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x))

```
.environments |= map(      
     select(.name | contains("docker"))
   | .database.database_config.host = "1.2.3.4"
)
```

Sample Run (assumes data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M '.environments |= map(select(.name | contains("docker")) | .database.database_config.host = "1.2.3.4")' data.json
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "docker",
      "database": {
        "name": "dgraph",
        "database_config": {
          "host": "1.2.3.4",
          "port": 9080
        }
      },
      "schemas": {
        "Thing": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weaviate/weaviate-semantic-schemas/master/weaviate-Thing-ontology-schema_org.min.json",
        "Action": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weaviate/weaviate-semantic-schemas/master/weaviate-Action-ontology-schema_org.min.json"
      },
      "mqttEnabled": false
    }
  ]
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/d9K97QJKHK)